# How to delete a imageview with a if statment?

Tags: android, imageview

If I ran an `if` statement, could I put something in there to delete a image view?

ex.

```
if (stuff || morestuff) 
{
    imageview1.delete
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Delete"? Remove the image from view, remove the bitmap from memory?

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap(null); 
If you want to remove the bitmap from memory
or you can set it to 0 but for some people it may not work

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Just from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the view from your parent view. or you can set the View visibility to Gone `yourImageView.setVisibilty(View.GONE)`

Comment: I appreciate the answer, can I run a if statement on visibility?

Comment: But isn't that the code to make it invisible?

Comment: Sure, you can. if you also want to make it visible(yourImageView.setVisibilty(View.VISIBILE))

Comment: I re added the comment after editing :) .. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: Whenever I run this, it changes the visibility for imageView11-16, Whats up with that?

Comment: Never mind, "GONE" = 8 so I set it to 7. That works. Thanks!